# Entity Framework Many-to-many update

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

An image has many galleries, and a gallery has many images. I am trying to update the images that a gallery has. The code below works, but feels somewhat clumsy.

```
   var g=db.Galleries.Find(gal.Id);

   var ims = gal.Images.Select(i => db.Images.Where(im => im.Id == i.Id && im.User.Id == user.Id)).SelectMany(im => im).ToList();

   g.Name = gal.Name;

   g.Images.Clear();

   foreach (var im in ims)
   {
        g.Images.Add(im);
   }

   db.SaveChanges();
```

When I do this:

```
g.Images=ims;
```

instead of:

```
   g.Images.Clear();

   foreach (var im in ims)
   {
        g.Images.Add(im);
   }
```

An exception is thrown:

```
Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_GalleryImages'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.GalleryImages'.
```

Can you explain why? Is there a better way to approach this?

Comment: are you trying to *update* existing images that a gallery has, or are you trying to *insert* new images into a gallery?

Comment: The why: a primary key enforces the rule that a record is unique (removing duplicates). So you can't insert the same record more than once in the table.

Comment: The test case which throws the exception is trying to do an update which logically is a no-op. ie no change to the set of images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `g.Images.Add(im)`, entity framework will add a new row with `galleryId` and `imageId` in `dbo.GalleryImages` table if it doesn't already exist in the table.

On the otherhand, when you do `g.Images=ims`, you are actually telling entity framework to add a new relation (new row in GalleryImages table). If you were to add new images into the gallery `g.Images=ims` would work fine.